# Maximum address Space range that can be utilize in a micro-controller

Tags: microcontroller

I have below assignment problem and I do not know my answer is correct or not.

the question is,

"A micro-controller is having only 8 address lines and another additional signal lines through a special register. compute the maximum address space range that can be utilize by the designer ?"

my answer is 2^(16) memory spaces. is my answer is correct? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All depends on how many "additional signal lines from a special register" are there.

If that other register gives 8 more lines, without further limitations, and the hardware is correct for such scenario, then yes, your reply is correct, you have 2^16 addresses.

But you didn't state how wide that registers is, and whether that register uses all its bits as address (or paging) lines, or whatever. But generally you are right, the address space width is 2^number_of_lines.

Comment: and there is no reason to assume there is only one bus, various busses in the design or off chip can have a different sized address space.

Comment: @old_timer absolutely true. You are old timer like me... and in the past we've seen some funny chips right?

Comment: I'm getting a bit lost in your answer here. You state that address space = 2^number of lines. And the question states a number of lines as 8, but you both state 16 as the right answer. How come?

Comment: @TarickWelling look deeply to the question, it says "only 8 address lines and another additional signal lines...". We both interpreted that as 8+X lines, otherwise there is no need to cite some "additional signal lines".